# Combine two queries into one effective query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I have a bit of a problem. Usually when I have two queries I would use `JOIN` to merge them together, but this time I can't seem to logically figure out how to do it the best since one of the queries also contain a subquery.

**Background:** I'm setting up a system where people can make posts. The users will then be able to follow other users and topics. So if a post gets tagged with "eduction" - the user will be able to follow the topic "education" - and see all the posts from this topic.

The two queries shows the desired content. But I would like to make a "feed" so the user will see the posts from the others users it follows and from the topics that it follows. I would really like to make it as effecient as possible and I would really like to learn how to handle this in the future myself, so if you could also explain how and why the "solution" would be the best - I would appreciate it.

**Query that displays the posts from the users followed:**

```
$query = "SELECT
    t.t_id,
    t.t_thought,
    t.t_timestamp,
    t.u_id AS t_u_id,
    t.t_statistics,
    t.t_reaction,
    t.t_comments,
    t.t_no_reactions,
    t.t_no_comments,
    u.u_id AS u_u_id,
    u.u_username,
    u.u_real_name,
    u.u_profile_picture,
    r.r_id
        FROM thoughts AS t
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.u_id = u.u_id
    INNER JOIN followers AS f ON f.u_id = '".$u_id."' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN reactions AS r ON r.u_id = ? AND r.t_id = t.t_id
    WHERE t.u_id = f.u_id_to_follow
    ORDER BY t_id DESC LIMIT ?, ?
";
```

**Query that displays the posts from the topics followed**

```
$queryGetThoughts = "SELECT
    t.t_id,
    t.t_thought,
    t.t_timestamp,
    t.u_id AS t_u_id,
    t.t_statistics,
    t.t_reaction,
    t.t_comments,
    t.t_no_reactions,
    t.t_no_comments,
    u.u_id AS u_u_id,
    u.u_username,
    u.u_real_name,
    u.u_profile_picture,
    r.r_id
        FROM thoughts AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        users AS u ON t.u_id = u.u_id
    INNER JOIN 
        thoughts_tags AS tt ON tt.t_id = t.t_id
    INNER JOIN 
        tags AS tags ON tt.tag_id = tags.tag_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN reactions AS r ON r.u_id = ? AND r.t_id = t.t_id
    WHERE tt.tag_id IN( SELECT tag_id FROM tags_followers WHERE u_id = '".$u_id."')
    GROUP BY t.t_id
    ORDER BY t.t_id DESC LIMIT ?, ?
";
```

I appreciate your help and knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: A [UNION clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) always works, but it doesn't increase the efficiency by much. Since you GROUP BY in one query, and not in the other, I don't see what more can be done?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Thank you very much! I made it work with a UNION clause. The effectiveness is probably questionable, but as a "temporary solution" - this works. I dont know how to calculate the effeciency - but if someone follows 30 topics and 30 users - with a lot of posts and reactions I think it will be ineffecient. But for now - thank you a lot.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Oh I just saw your edit: I GROUP BY in one of them because users are unique, but if a post is tagged with "education" and "library" and I follow both topics, I will get 2 results = GROUP BY. Now - with UNION it makes even more sense to GROUP BY :)

Comment: You can, instead of `GROUP BY` use `SELECT DISTINCT`, but only if you get two exactly the same results. That does, in those circumstances, more or less, the same thing. If the `GROUP BY` was the only real difference between the two queries, apart from the `WHERE` bit, you could combine them, but there are more differences. Anyway, trying to do too much in one query might not make it more efficient, but it certainly will make it harder to understand and maintain. Sometimes multiple queries are your friend.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Thank you again for your thoughts on this. It all makes sense and I will carry on the current code, since you're right. Two queries like this is easier to understand and maintain than one big cluster - I agree. I am always concerned about performence though. I don't know why - but I always want things to run as fast as possible within my set of skills - especially if a project like this would "all of the sudden" blow up and get 10.000 users. Thank you very much for your time so far.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I know this is a bit "off topic" - but when looking at these queries. Can you tell me which of these you would make an index on?

Comment: Oh, selecting correct indexes is a bit of an art form, and goes way to far to answer in a comment. I have noticed many people only make indexes on one column, but actually you can create one index on multiple columns. Quite often that gives the best results. A good way to test your queries is to generate bogus data. For instance, if you want to be able to work with 10,000 users and 10,000,000 posts, then create those, and test your queries.